# How to mimic --device option in docker run in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am very new to Kubernetes and docker. Am trying to find the config equivalent of --device option in docker run. This option in docker is used to add a device on the host to the container. 
Is there a equivalent in kubernetes which can be added to the yaml file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently we do not have a passthrough to this option in the API, though you may have some success with using a hostpath volume to mount a device file in.

Comment: Thanks i did try the same. I had volume also to be specified and hence have used hostpath (for devices) and emptydir (for volume). However the container creation fails with API error (500): No command specified.

Comment: I had missed the command option inside the yaml file which caused the failure. I am able to create the docker now. However on inspecting the docker i see a difference in way these configs are applied when pushed as device and volume.

Comment: Yeah, the hostpath bind-mount of device is not the same as --device.  Do feel free to create an issue for this in the kubernetes project if you really want it!

Comment: Hi Paul, just figured out that an issue is already created in Git   https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/17066